# Problems with reading two pages with Chrome and Firefox on Windows 10

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox

When I visit two different url the pages I get the message:

> Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.

Sometimes the page is visible for a second, but then it disappears. . Other times there is no page at all.

This happens for https://support.google.com and https://cpanel.brattnet.com
with Chrome and Firefox on Windows 10, but not for any other url that I have tested.

There is no problem with Edge on Windows 10 or Chrome and Firefox on Android.

I have recently installed Microsoft OneDrive and Office365.

What can I do?

---

Thanks for your advice, Twisty Impersonator. I have now tried Firefox with another profile, but get the same result. "Arghh. Your tab just crashed."

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This is most likely due to a problem with your browser profile. Try creating a second profile in one of these browsers (instructions can be found online) and see if the problem goes away. Report back here. Please do not respond in the comments. Instead, [edit] the post with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
1. Clear your cache.
2. Close other tabs, extensions, and apps.
3. Update Chrome and Firefox.
4. Check for unwanted software.
Please refer to: [Fix "Aw, Snap!" page crashes and other page loading errors](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en) and
[Firefox can't load websites but other browsers can](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can)

Comment: I have now done everything that was mentioned in the two links you provided. I have also completely removed and installed Chrome and Firefox. But still the same problem.

When I use tools for programmers and look att Networks I find that when Chrome reads 
https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/k=og.qtm.en_US.pKUjEu8LGiw.O/rt=j/m=q_d,q...
I get the message CAUTION: request is not finished yet! Can it has something to do with the problem?